# Opening an old page from new url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My new URL is /charts/radar-spider-charts/ and the page which should be opened is
/charts/radar-spider-chart (the 's/' is removed). Can I do that in .htaccess. I'm new to Htaccess so need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple 301 redirect using the following:

```
Redirect 301 /charts/radar-spider-charts/ /charts/radar-spider-chart
```

Alternatively, you can use `mod_rewrite` if you need extended redirects or don't want the URL to change in the user's browser.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^charts/radar-spider-charts/?$ /charts/radar-spider-chart [R=301]
```

Comment: no i didn't mean redirect. the URL in browser should display /charts/radar-spider-charts/

Comment: Please see the alternative I have added (i.e. using `mod_rewrite`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(charts/radar-spider-chart)s/?$ /$1 [L,NC]
```